# ¿Attempt to index local 'items' (a nil value)?

Tags: lua

Este es el código, y el error me aparece en esta sección, no se mucho de lua o programacion y me gustaria pedir ayuda para esto porque no encuentro mas informacion y mira que he buscado en internet para ver como solucionarlo.

Item.lua:61: attempt to index local 'items' (a nil value)

Item.lua:61: in function

Item.lua:127: in function `CreateMaps'

Item.lua:245: in function  [C]: ?

```js
local function AddMapping(map, key, ...)
    map[key] = {};
    local items = Utils.Pack(...); 

    for i = 1, items.n do  --aquí me aparace el error
        map[key][items[i]] = true;
    end
end
```

Archivo Completo:
[Item.lua](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar9nSlIgqzQfqzQLI0wSkcKj-zZL)

Comment: Bienvenido @EnriqueSephiMoralesSánchez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Es importante indicar que el archivo ha sido tomado de [https://github.com/Necroskillz/StatWeightScore/blob/master/src/Item.lua](https://github.com/Necroskillz/StatWeightScore/blob/master/src/Item.lua) siempre hay que dar crédito al autor original... asimismo es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) porque en tu pregunta se pide revisar todo el repositorio con la modificación que has hecho y por tanto ya sería demasiado amplia.

Comment: Asimismo sería oportuno indicar que el anterior Repositorio corresponde a un MOOD llamado **Stat Weight Score** para hacer simulaciones craft  ([inglés](https://wow.curseforge.com/projects/stat-weight-score)) en [World WarCraft](https://www.wowhead.com/how-to-use-simulationcraft-and-pawn), en ese sentido considero que la pregunta  antes de ser modificada... sí respondía al error señalado inicialmente, pero con este archivo posteado y al ver que no es propio, siento decir que he reportado la pregunta al no ser ya especifica, porque su respuesta involucra otros conceptos como...

Comment: Programación orientada a objetos con tablas ([inglés](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)), porque **LUA** se maneja mediante este paradigma haciendo portable al mismo. Por otro lado, al tenerse varias bibliotecas conexas al código **[Character.lua](https://github.com/Necroskillz/StatWeightScore/blob/master/src/Character.lua)** se tiene que rastrear como han sido programada las clases y los métodos que se importan como bibliotecas, porque éstas no son propias de **LUA**, por tanto, esa investigación ya no corresponde a la comunidad de **Stack Overflow**, sino al que formula la pregunta...

Comment: Y si se tiene alguna duda, venir acá y efectuar la pregunta específica correspondiente, teniendo en cuenta, la casuística y lo que se espera lograr, sin olvidar ,mostrar el código debidamente explicado, detallándose además, las dificultades y lo que se ha intentado.

Answer (score 0):

### Consideraciones

La función `Utils.pack` no es propia de **Lua**, al parecer se está empleando la biblioteca `Penlight`

Sobre el particular, al revisar estos enlace:

1. https://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/source/test.lua.html
2. https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/utils.lua

Se hace referencia a la función `unpack` de **Lua** en el primer enlace

```
local print,type,unpack = print,type,utils.pack
```

Mientras que en el segundo a `table.pack`

```
utils.pack = table.pack  -- added here to be symmetrical with unpack
```

Entonces, hay una especie de contradicción en la documentación, porque la misma función `utils.pack` es definida para **empaquetar** y **desempaquetar** una tabla al mismo tiempo.

No obstante lo anterior, siento decir qué `table.pack` sólo está disponible a partir de **Lua 5.2**, en tal sentido, algunos **SDK**, como **CORONA, GIDEROS MOBILE,** etc. no disponen de dicha característica actualmente.

Pero, viendo la función `AddMappin` se puede comprender lo que se quiere lograr, `items.n` da el número de elementos que tiene la tabla después de aplicar la función `Utils.pack(...)` pero de acuerdo a la documentación `items.n` sólo existe sí se aplica la función `utils.unpack`

```
function utils.unpack(t, i, j) # Utils.pack no devuelve t.n porque es igual a table.pack
    return _unpack(t, i or 1, j or t.n or #t)
end
```

De lo expuesto, queda claro entonces que

```
local items = Utils.Pack(...)
```

Sería lo mismo a

```
local items = table.pack(...)
```

No obstante, como `table.pack` sólo corre en **Lua 5.2** se puede emplear `in pairs` en el bucle `for`, lo cual es similar a `enumerate` en **Python** por ejemplo.

> La sintaxis en **Lua** no requiere que al finalizar una sentencia, se le coloque el (`;`) sólo se emplea, si se pone varias sentencias en una misma línea, pero no al final.

```
local a={}; for i=1,10 do a[#a+1]=i*i end; print(unpack(a))
-- 1   4   9   16  25  36  49  64  81  100
```

### Alternativa

Como mencioné se puede emplear `in pairs` para indexar una tabla, aquí un pequeño ejemplo

```
items = {false,true,1,0,"hola"}
for index, item in pairs(items) do 
    print (index, item)
end
--[[
      1   false
      2   true
      3   1
      4   0
      5   hola
]]
```

En tal sentido, la función `AddMapping`, debe recibir la tabla items ya construida, si no se emplea **Lua 5.2** y ese debe ser el motivo del error que se ha tenido `items.n` no existe... (en realidad su existencia está condicionada a la función `utils.unpack()`) por eso el bucle `for` no tiene sobre qué iterar.

Adicionalmente, es útil emplear dicho método (`in pairs`) porque si la lista tuviera algún `nil` daría error si se indexa como se ha plasmado en la función de la pregunta, aquí un ejemplo:

```
local items = {false,true,nil,"hola"}
items.n = #items -- numero de elementos en la table items

local map= {}
map["llave"]={}
print(unpack(items))
-- false   true    nil hola

for i=1, items.n do 
    map["llave"][items[i]] = true
end
--[[
lua: [string "<eval>"]: table index is nil
stack traceback:
    [string "<eval>"]:: in main chunk
]]
```

La situación si bien se soluciona con `in pairs` a veces se hace necesario mantener los `nil`, pero como en la pregunta no se ha expuesto que tipo de estructura se quiere lograr... voy ha asumir que se desea mantener los `nil` para ello se puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
for i=1, items.n do
    item = items[i]==nil and 'nil' or items[i]
    map["llave"][tostring(item)] = true  
end
```

> Si el último elemento en la tabla fuera `nil` simplemente **Lua** lo omite, por tanto, lo anterior sólo va funcionar para elementos `nil` que estén entre valores de una tabla.

```
print(#{nil,nil,nil}) -- se imprime cero
print(#{nil,nil,nil,23}) -- se imprime cuatro
print(#{nil,nil,nil,23,nil}) -- se imprime cero
```

### Respuesta

De lo expuesto la función quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
local function AddMapping(map, key, items)
      local map = map or {} -- si solo se define local map={} es una
                            -- variable interna no seria necesario
                            -- configurarla desde fuera, con esta
                            -- forma se da chance a construir
                            -- estructuras más complejas

      local items = items or {}   -- como el bucle for inicia en 1 
                                  -- minimo deberia debería tener
                                  -- un elemento la lista

      items.n = #items            -- numero de elementos en la lista
      map[key] = {}

      if items.n > 0 then         -- si hay elementos en lista se entra
                                  -- al bucle
        local item                -- se define siempre fuera de los
                                  -- bucles las variables locales
        for i=1, items.n do
            -- la expresion de abajo en similar al condicional 'if'
            -- item = if 'items[i]==nil' then 'nil' else 'items[i]' end
            item = items[i]==nil and 'nil' or items[i]

            map[key][tostring(item)] = true       -- si el elemento es un numero
                                                  -- para usarlo como clave
                                                  -- se convierte en texto
        end

      end

      return map
end
```

Probando la función con algunos ejemplos

```
test = AddMapping({}, "llave1", {false,true,1,0,"hola"})
for k, v in pairs(test["llave1"]) do print(k,v) end
--[[
    -- se imprime de acuerdo a la clave de la columna izquirda en texto
    1       true
    0       true
    false   true
    true    true
    hola    true
]]

print(test["llave1"]["0"]) -- se imprime true

test = AddMapping(test, "llave2", {"adios",nil,false,20})
for k, v in pairs(test["llave2"]) do print(k,v) end
--[[
    adios   true
    nil true
    20  true
    false   true
]]
```

### Ampliación Respuesta

Como se aprecia, se puede ir aumentando la complejidad de la tabla `test`, agregando tantos niveles o subniveles sea necesario, en ese sentido, se hace necesario contar con un método que permita visualizar la estructura que se va creando.

Sobre lo anterior, hace algunos años hablé con @ar2rsawseen en este post [LuaJIT and Json: Error reading 'null'](http://forum.giderosmobile.com/discussion/comment/35387/#Comment_35387), facilitándome aquella vez, una función recursiva que voy a compartir en esta respuesta para imprimir tablas complejas en **Lua**.

```
function print_r (t, indent, done)
  done = done or {}
  indent = indent or ''
  local nextIndent -- Almacenamiento para el siguiente valor de sangría
  for key, value in pairs (t) do
    if type (value) == "table" and not done [value] then
      nextIndent = nextIndent or
          (indent .. string.rep(' ',string.len(tostring (key))+2))
          -- Asignación condicional de atajo
      done [value] = true
      print (indent .. "[" .. tostring (key) .. "] => Table {");
      print  (nextIndent .. "{");
      print_r (value, nextIndent .. string.rep(' ',2), done)
      print  (nextIndent .. "}");
    else
      print  (indent .. "[" .. tostring (key) .. "] => " .. tostring (value).."")
    end
  end
end
```

Aplicándose sobre la table `test` obtenida con la función `AddMapping`

```
print_r(test)
--[[
    [llave2] => Table {
            {
              [adios] => true
              [nil] => true
              [20] => true
              [false] => true
            }
    [llave1] => Table {
            {
              [1] => true
              [0] => true
              [false] => true
              [true] => true
              [hola] => true
            }

]]
```

El código mostrado puede ser ejecutado en [repl.it que es Lua 5.1.5](https://repl.it/repls/ColorfulWateryRobodoc)

Finalmente una sugerencia, a veces trabajar con `nil` en tablas con **Lua** puede llevarte a una empresa sin mucho éxito, en su lugar recomendaría que el `nil` sea un `string` (`'nil'` o `"nil"`), si se le necesita como dato en una tabla.

Asimismo el `nil` debería ser empleado para destruir objetos si no pueden ser reutilizados y liberar memoria o en su defecto ser reemplazados por un `false` si se tiene por ejemplo implementado un `pool` y las posiciones de una tabla no deben perderse porque se hace referencia especificas a ellas, sobre todo cuando se está iterando las tablas mediante un `while` un `coroutine` o `timers`.